# Return a certain value if two cells from two different column match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 set of data.

Column A equals ID;
Column B equals Name;
Column I equals Name;

What I would like to have is: `if B1 = I1, then H1 = A1.`

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in `H1`, I'll trust you have something in mind for when it doesn't match, for now it will say "False"

`=if(B1=I1,A1,"False")`

Comment: That should work. If not, you are getting the syntax wrong, or may be using a non-English version of Excel, which uses different language and semi-colons instead of commas. If you mouse click in different parts of the formula, a small pop-up guide should appear with help debug or enter the formula. Does this appear?

Comment: @Chna have you looked into DrWhat's comment regarding the syntax and language settings?